# Load template in AngularJS except for current page

Tags: templates, angularjs

Say I have 2 HTML pages, `foo.html` and `bar.html`.

Inside `foo.html`:

```html
<a href="/foo.html" class="selected">Open Foo</a>
<a href="/bar.html">Open Bar</a>
<!-- shared content -->
<div id="content">Nested HTML specific to Foo</div>
<!-- shared content -->
```

Inside `bar.html`:

```html
<a href="/foo.html">Open Foo</a>
<a href="/bar.html" class="selected">Open Bar</a>
<!-- shared content -->
<div id="content">Nested HTML specific to Bar</div>
<!-- shared content -->
```

As expected, when I click a link in either page, it will open the corresponding page. Now, I want to "AngularJSify" this so that clicking a link will only update `div#content`. I tried this:

```js
$routeProvider
.when('/foo.html', {templateUrl:'/foo.html?onlyContent=true'})
.when('/bar.html', {templateUrl:'/bar.html?onlyContent=true'})
```

```html
<div id="content" ng-view>Nested HTML specific to Foo (or Bar, depending which page you're in)</div>
```

But opening `foo.html` will also load `foo.html?onlyContent=true` which is unnecessary because `foo.html` already has the content!

You might be asking, "Why not use empty `div#content`?" Because I want to (1) Reduce loading extra file, and (2) Make the content available even if JS is disabled.

In Backbone.js I can use:

```js
Backbone.history.start({pushState:true, silent:true});
```

Which basically means, "If the page is already loaded, don't invoke the route again." How do I achieve that in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `foo.html`:

```html
<a href="/foo.html" class="selected">Open Foo</a>
<a href="/bar.html">Open Bar</a>
<div id="defaultTemplate">Nested HTML specific to Foo</div> <!-- note this -->
<div id="content" ng-view></div>
```

Inside `bar.html`:

```html
<a href="/foo.html">Open Foo</a>
<a href="/bar.html" class="selected">Open Bar</a>
<div id="defaultTemplate">Nested HTML specific to Bar</div> <!-- note this -->
<div id="content" ng-view></div>
```

In JavaScript:

```js
function routing(path, controller, template) {
    var route = {templateUrl:'/templates/' + path, controller:controller};

    if (path === window.location.pathname) {
        var defaultTemplate = $('#defaultTemplate');

        route = {template:defaultTemplate.html(), controller:controller};
        defaultTemplate.remove();
    }

    $routeProvider.when(path, route);
}
```

Essentially means, "if the route you're opening is the same with the path in address bar, use template from current page instead".